# Event on image in scrollable Canvas (Python)

Tags: python, image, loops, events, scrollbar

want to load thumbnails of images into a scrollable region by a loop. Therefore I have created a canvas which contains the images. By clicking on one of the images, a larger version should appear in another frame. So I need to transfer e.g. the file path to the event function.

Here is an example with a working scrollable region and some rectangles representing my images outside of this region. Clicking on the recrtangles gives me the image information. But as soon as I insert all the rectangles into the scrollable region, the rectangles won't move during scrolling.

What do I have to change?

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ttk import *

def OnClick(event, obj):
    print "you clicked on", obj
    for path, objectname in filedict.items():
        if objectname == obj:
            print path

root = tk.Tk()
canv = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg='green')
sbarV = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical")
sbarV.config(command=canv.yview)
sbarV.pack(side="right", fill="y")      
canv.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
canv.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canv.pack_propagate(0)
canv.create_text(7,7,width=185, anchor="nw", font=("Arial", 7), text='example')

filedict = {}
for i in range(10):
    filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'] = tk.Canvas(root, width=50, height=30, bg='red')
    filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'].pack()
    filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'].create_rectangle(0,0,20,20, fill="black", tags=str(i))
    filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'].bind("<1>", lambda event, obj=filedict[str(i) + '.jpg']: OnClick(event, obj))

canv.config(scrollregion=(0,0,300,1000))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution how to insert the canvas into the scroll region. A window is needed an the loop looks like this now:

```
for i in range(10):
    filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'] = tk.Canvas(canv, width=50, height=30, bg='red')
    filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'].pack()
    filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'].create_rectangle(0,0,20,20, fill="black", tags=str(i))
    filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'].bind("<1>", lambda event, obj=filedict[str(i) + '.jpg']: OnClick(event, obj))
    canv.create_window(80,20+i*40, window=filedict[str(i) + '.jpg'])
```